# How to configure properly JNDI for tomcat 6 and its deployed webapps?

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat6, jndi, derby

I have an embedded derby db with tables for USERS, ROLES, USERS_ROLES, etc. My requirement is using it for tomcat authentication. Additionaly, i've created an spring webapp in order to administrate the Users, Roles, etc. in a simplier way.

Previously i have defined this datasource in my applicationContext:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:derby:C:\tools\derbydb"
    p:connectionProperties=""
    p:username="APP"
    p:password="" />
```

I've changed this aproach to JNDI and now i've defined the db resource in webapp/WEB-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/adminDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" username="APP" password=""
            driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
            url="jdbc:derby:C:\tools\derbydb"/>
</Context>
```

And in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/adminDB"/>
</bean>
```

In eclipse it works ok. I can read the values, edit, log in, etc.

My problem is relative to allow this on tomcat 6. I've read some pages including questions of stackoverflow but i don't find my specific problem. I've deployed another app which use the tomcat security in order to access some data. It is an app developed by a third party. With the old configuration works fine (server.xml):

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" driverName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:derby:C:\tools\derbydb" connectionName="APP" connectionPassword="" userTable="USERS" userNameCol="USERNAME" userCredCol="PASSWORD" userRoleTable="V_USERS_ROLES" roleNameCol="ROLENAME"/>
```

and i was able to login with the users defined in the database using tomcat. But now, i defined something like this (server.xml) :

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/adminDB" userTable="USERS" userNameCol="USERNAME" userCredCol="PASSWORD" userRoleTable="V_USERS_ROLES" roleNameCol="ROLENAME"/>
```

and in the server.xml (GlobalNamingResources)

```
<Resource name="jdbc/adminDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" username="APP" password=""
        driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
        url="jdbc:derby:C:\tools\derbydb"/>
```

When i try to log in i get this error:

```
SEVERE: Excepci¾n realizando autenticaci¾n
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Failed to s
tart database 'C:\tools\derbydb' with class loader org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@23
49e5ef, see the next exception for details.)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSour
ce.java:1549)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open(DataSourceRealm.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.authenticate(DataSourceRealm.java:296)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java
:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.ja
va:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:\tools\derbydb' with class loader org.
apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@2349e5ef, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFact
ory.java:38)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactor
y.java:582)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.jav
a:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSour
ce.java:1545)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:\tools\derbydb' with class loader org.
apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@2349e5ef, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown S
ource)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\
tools\derbydb.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown S
ource)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\tools\derb
ydb.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown So
urce)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)

        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
        ... 25 more
```

It seems like an app of another JVM has locked the derby db. But i don't have anything accessing to the db excepting the tomcat itself. And i've not deployed the admin webapp at the momment. I've only deployed the app which uses the tomcat login. Does anybody know what is happening?

By the way... is this solution correct in order to access the db from the admin webapp? Or do i need to define the resource in the context.xml?

Any helping answer will be voted

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each separate application within a single Tomcat application server is considered a separate instance of Derby.

So two different applications in the same Tomcat app server cannot access the same copy of Derby, unless you use the Client-Server configuration of Derby and configure a Derby Network Server.

Comment: thank you for answer me Bryan! And.. if the elements which access to the derby db are the tomcat authentication and an app to administrate the db, is this situation considered as separate instances? in other words... is it mandatory to use derby network in my case? thank you very much.